# react and nodejs: MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]

Tags: node.js, express

> MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
>       at new MongooseError (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:10:11)
>       at Function.Model.$handleCallbackError (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4604:11)
>       at Function.Model.findByIdAndUpdate (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2561:19)
>       at router.put (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\routes\librarys.js:86:41)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at param (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
>       at param (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
>       at next (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\libraryapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     message: 'Callback must be a function, got [object Object]',
>     name: 'MongooseError' }

Comment: post your code where your facing issue

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)